# How to display a modal window during a drag operation?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop

In the `performDragOperation(sender: NSDraggingInfo)` method of the receiver of my drag operation, I want to display a modal window that requires user input. The URL of a file that is dropped will populate one field in the modal window, and the user will have to populate another NSTextField.

The problem is that the modal window does not respond to keyboard events during the drag operation, which effectively causes a deadlock until the drag times out. I cannot find a reliable way to deal with this. I have two possible workarounds, neither solves this completely:

1. Use `dispatch_after()` to tell the main thread to show the modal window 0.25 sec after the drag operation completes. This works, but is dependent on a race condition.
2. Instead of a modal window, simply show a regular window. Or use `beginModalSession()`. Less desirable than a modal window in this case.

Code:

```
override func performDragOperation(sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
    // Do some stuff here to get data from the sender

    // Load a view controller and display it modally
    let vc = MyViewController(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: nil) {
        self.presentViewControllerAsModalWindow(vc)
    }
    return true
}
```

I've tried using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {}` to present the view controller. I thought that would allow `performDragOperation` to return true, but that does not appear to be sufficient to end the drag operation completely.

I've also tried showing the view controller from `concludeDragOperation()`, but that does not help either.

What is the best practice to deal with this situation?